# Is the rdrand instruction available on AMD FX 8350?

Tags: random, amd-processor, rdrand

I am evaluating the feasibility of moving a simulation to a FX 8350.
Is there a document on the availability (if not, a workaround) of the rdrand instruction of Intel's BullMountain on AMD FX 8350?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, RDRAND is not present in AMD FX 8350 as well as in any other Piledriver platform based chip. I believe AMD implemented RDRAND in Zen architecture/platform